# Can a stackdriver account monitor resources in a different organization in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have the following scenario

1. Org 1 ----> GCP Project 1 ( hosting project for stackdriver account)
2. Org 2 ----> GCP Project 2

I want the stackdriver account in Project 1 to be able to monitor the resources in Project 2 which happens to be in a different organization , is it possible with stackdriver on GCP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have the right access to each project, stackdriver can monitor across different organizations.